# How to get metrics of bunches of short-lived Kubernetes jobs

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, cadvisor

I have a case that short-lived(from seconds to 1-2 minutes) k8s jobs will be created on user request. I'm trying to retrieve job runtime metrics(like cpu and memory usage).

The methods I've thought of(and tried) includes:

1. Prometheus query, like `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`, but pull-based scape means that many short-lived jobs will not be included
2. Pushgateway, but as prometheus suggests, [...valid use case for the Pushgateway is for capturing the outcome of a service-level batch job](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/#should-i-be-using-the-pushgateway), so I doubt this is not the suitable case.
3. Metric-server, but metric-server only returns 404 on short-lived job pods, leading to worse results than Prometheus.
4. Query `/api/v1/nodes/{nodeName}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor` directly. Though almost real-time, it returns all containers, so I have to manually parse the results and find what I need.

I'm thinking of using a lightweight monitor container beside the job worker container to retrieve the worker's metrics. But I don't know whether this is a good idea, and even if so, how to retrieve the worker's metrics.

So my question is:

What method do you recommend to retrieve a large number of short-lived jobs' cpu and memory usage?

Comment: Before you proceed with anything, I'd suggest you consider why this is important to monitor. 
Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying it's not worth monitoring, I'm just asking you to *really* consider why it is. It may be worth you investing your time at other things than attempting to monitor short-lived jobs and their impact on CPU and memory - **unless** it's impacting your service. So it might be enough monitoring how many jobs get fired off, rather than their overall impact (unless service health goes to shit).

Answer (score -2):

As you wrote you used prometheus, pushgateways, metrics-server ns query /api/v1/nodes/{nodeName}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor if they don't satisfy you enough new approach which I recommend of montitoring and metrics saving of cluster performance is Litmus.

Prometheus is most common and complex tool which may be used by most of engineers but Litmus is kind new tool which is focused on workload testing, metrics are saved and you can store them as long as you want.

More information you can find here: [litmus](https://github.com/litmuschaos/litmus).

Useful artice: [litmus-openebs](https://blog.openebs.io/storage-chaos-engineering-with-litmus-an-overview-ef6d8f1e89fd), this describe not to get metrics  not only like memory usage.

Then you can generate charts in egg. gnuplot.